# Azure Cloud Services REST API - Get Package returning 404

Tags: rest, azure, service, package, cloud

Is this “Get Package” API still supported:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154121.aspx
Seems like it always return HTTP 404.

I’m able to successfully use the “Get Deployment” API documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx

But can’t get the /package resource to work. Note that I'm using the same certificate for authentication that I use for the "Get Deployment" API, and it works fine.

My call to the API looks exactly like in the MSDN documentation.

Is there any other way to retrieve the Service Package (.cspkg) file of a deployed cloud service?

Answer (score 0):

The Get Package operation is still supported. It's likely that if you're getting a 404 response that you're using a HTTP GET method as opposed to POST. I've tested the operation using the REST Console plugin for Chrome and my package was successfully written to blob storage.

The URI used was:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deploymentslots/<deployment-slot>/package?containerUri=<container-uri>
```